# Why is LiAlH4 a stronger reducing agent than DIBAL-H

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction

Asides the different number of hydrogens, why is LiAlH4 a stronger and less selective reducing agent than DIBAL-H

Comment: How did you try to solve the problem? It will help the answerers to answer your question! (I was going to say welcome to chem.SE, but it seems like you have been here a while)

Answer (score 2):

If you consider $\ce{LiAlH_4}$ and $\ce{DIBAL-H}$(Di-isobutyl Aluminium Hydride), other than different no. of Hydrogens attached to them, they also have significant structural dissimilarities between them. 
 First of all, in $\ce{LiAlH_4}$, the reducing agent is $\ce{H^-}$, which comes from ionic $\ce{AlH_4^-}$. As, the compound is ionic it is easier for the anion to donate $\ce{H^-}$, and after donation also, the remaining $\ce{AlH_3}$, can get high stabilisation by dimerising to $\ce{Al_2H_6}$. So, the rate of formation of $\ce{H^-}$ is very high from $\ce{LiAlH_4}$, which makes it stronger reducing agent.
 On the other hand, **Di-isobutyl Aluminium Hydride** is a pure covalent compound. It is difficult for it to donate reducing $\ce{H^-}$, and after donation also, it can't get any extra stabilisation. Thus, eventually, it becomes weaker reducing agent. 
 Now coming to selectivity, ***if you have a high concentration of reductant (here $\ce{H^-}$), the probablity of forming all possible products automatically increases, because the kinetic control of the reaction overcomes the thermodynamic control.But, on the other case, less concentration of the reductant doesn't allow the kinetic control to exceed thermodynamic control, and thus the more selective product(which is actually thermodynamically more stable) is formed***. Thus, huge concentration of $\ce{H^-}$ makes $\ce{LiAlH_4}$ less selective and more reactive.

Comment: Thanks, but in terms of the reduction of cinnamaldehyde, why is LiAlH4 able to fully reduce it as appose to DIBAL reducing it to an allylic alcohol. Except the availability of a second hydrogen for the hydroalumination of the C=C?

Comment: Do you know the fact that $LiAlH_4$ can reduce double bonds only if it is highly conjugated??